# Como seleccionar un id que esta en otro id desde CSS

Tags: css

No soy para nada bueno con el css y tengo la siguiente duda.

Ya tengo el formato del menú de la pagina y no lo puedo cambiar ya que es para múltiples paginas el css (Padre css).

La idea es que muestre un menu para Desktop y que muestre otro para telefono y tablet

Entonces tengo:

```
<nav>
            <ul **id="menu"**> -->para Desktop 
                <li class="act"><a href="/inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="act"><a href="/producto.html">Productos</a></li>
                <li class="act"><a href="/commercial.html">Commercial</a></li>
                <li class="act"><a href="/nosotros.html">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
                <li class="act"><a href="/contacto.html">Contactar</a></li>


            </ul>

            <div id="mobile"> --> para celular y tablet
                <ul **id="menu"**>
            <li class="act"><a href="/inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="act"><a href="#" class="menutop">Productos</a>
                      <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="col_1">
                            <a href="/sala.html">para sala</a>
                            <a href="/bano.html">para Bano</a>
                        </div>
                      <span class="close-btn-menu">X</span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="act"><a href="/contacto.html">Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
```

Todo esto me funciona perfecto si uso javascript

```
if (window.innerWidth<= 768){
    document.getElementById('mobile').style.display ="block";
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display ="none";
    }else{

    document.getElementById('mobile').style.display ="none";
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display ="block";

    }
```

pero a la hora de pasarlo a css, no se como hacerlo :(, ya que id="menu" esta en las dos secciones (Desktop, celular ) y si le doy #menu{ display: none;} #mobile{ display: block;} me muestra el menu de Desktop

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso te pasa porque tenes dos id "menu", al menu desktop podrías contenerlo dentro de un div id "desktop" y actualizar tu js.

```
<div id="desktop>
    <ul **id="menu"**> -->para Desktop 
        <li class="act"><a href="/inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="act"><a href="/producto.html">Productos</a></li>
        <li class="act"><a href="/commercial.html">Commercial</a></li>
        <li class="act"><a href="/nosotros.html">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
        <li class="act"><a href="/contacto.html">Contactar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Tu js corregido:

```
if (window.innerWidth<= 768){
       document.getElementById('mobile').style.display ="block";
       document.getElementById('desktop').style.display ="none";
    }else{
       document.getElementById('mobile').style.display ="none";
       document.getElementById('desktop').style.display ="block";
    }
```

Si querés hacerlo con CSS seteale *display:none* a mobile y utilizá la etiqueta **media**:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   #mobile { display:block; }
   #desktop { display:none; }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Te lo agradezco muchísimo también funciono perfectamente!!!.

Answer (score 1):

CSS toma el ultimo valor osea tú #mobile #menu, por eso lo esconde, ya que id solo afecta a 1 y solo 1 elemento, por eso te afecta a tu menú en mobile, podrías apuntar a el de la siguiente manera:

```
#menu { display: none; } 
#mobile > #menu { display: block; }
```

Aunque te recomiendo le cambies el id, o lo vuelvas una clase.

Comment: Gracias te lo agradezco muchísimo enserió :)